# Is there a REST API for Windows Server Update Catalog?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-update, automatic-updates

Is there an API or Notification System for https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx - so that I can be aware of the update availability as and when they become available ?

What is the best way to proactively look for it in an automated manner?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/update-server-server-sync  may help

Answer (score 3):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/rss-feed-picker

Select a product, get the RSS or Atom feed for its updates.
Repeat for all products you are interested in.